# Which one of these is an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the sets $$G_1=\{x+y\sqrt{3} | x,y \in \mathbb{Z}, x^2-3y^2=1\}$$ and
$$G_2=\{x+y\sqrt{3} | x,y \in \mathbb{Q}, x^2-3y^2=1\}.$$
Which one of $(G_1,\cdot)$ and $(G_2, \cdot)$ is an abelian group, where $\cdot$ denotes the multiplication of the real numbers?
I think that both of them are abelian groups, because to me it seems that they both satisfy the group axioms(they are commutative and associative due to the fact that the multiplication of reals satisfies these conditions etc). However, my book says that only $(G_2,\cdot)$ is a group without providing any explanation. I don't understand why $(G_1,\cdot)$ isn't a group.

Comment: Maybe $G_1$ is not closed?

Comment: @Derek Allums I am quite sure that it is closed. Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: No, but it was just a hunch; that or some inverse isn't in the set. The fact that the only difference is one has elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ and the other in $\mathbb{Q}$ usually hints at this sort of thing. The algebra that it is closed was not obvious though.

Comment: I am fairly sure, your book is wrong about $G_1$ and it is indeed a group.

Comment: @DerekAllums If $G_2$ is closed, then $G_1$ will also be closed. (Because when you multiply elements of $G_2$ with integer coefficients, you will still have integer coefficients.)

Comment: $(x+y\sqrt{3})(x-y\sqrt{3})=x^2-3y^2=1$ and $x^2-3(-y)^2=1$, so inverses are indeed in the set.

Comment: $\ G_1\ $ looks very much to me like the group of units in the [quadratic integer ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer#Quadratic_integer_rings) $\ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]\ $.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for their interest ! Indeed, it seems that the book was wrong. @lhf it is a textbook from my country for high school seniors, so it is not a renowned abstract algebra book. This is why I had my doubts about their answer.

Comment: When I saw the title, I thought this question was about abelianness as opposed to groupiness, saw ordinary multiplication and did a double take... might as well be "which one is a group?" (which seems to be both)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $$G_1=\{x+y\sqrt{3} | x,y \in \mathbb{Z}, x^2-3y^2=1\}$$ 
Lets have a look at all group properties one by one.

**Associativity** and **identity element** are trivial to verify.

**Inverse** let $x+y\sqrt{3}\in G_1$. We want to find $a+b\sqrt{3} \ \in G_1$ such that the product equals 1. Then $(x+y\sqrt{3})\cdot (a+b\sqrt{3}) = 1$ implies

$$\left\{ \begin{align*}
ax+3by&=1\\
ay+bx&=0
\end{align*}\right.$$

Note that we cannot have an element with $x=0$ in $G_1$ (this would imply $y=-1/3$ but by condition $y\in\mathbb{Z}$), therefore 
$$\left\{ \begin{align*}
&b=-\frac{ay}{x}\\
&a\left(x-3\frac{y^2}{x}\right)=1
\end{align*}\right.$$
Using the fact that $x^2-3y^2=1$ the second line yields $a=x$ and therefore $b=-y$, and indeed $(x-y\sqrt{3})(x+y\sqrt{3})=1$ using the condition in $G_1$. The **inverse property is verified**

**Closure** This is again simple computation. Lets $a+b\sqrt{3}$ and $x+y\sqrt{3}$ be two elements of $G_1$, and lets looks at their products. Obviously the product can be written as $c+d\sqrt{3}$ with $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we only need to check the condition. 
We have 
$$\left\{ \begin{align*}
c&=ax+3by\\
d&=ay+bx 
\end{align*}\right.$$
Computing $c^2-3d^2$, using both facts that $a^2=1+3b^2$ and $x^2=1+3y^2$, we do ends up with $c^2-3d^2=1$ (I'll let you do the math, it's pretty straightforward). The **closure property is verified**

**As far as i can tell $(G_1,\cdot)$ is a group**.